# jboss-as-maven-plugin can't deploy to domain mode clustered Jboss AS 7?

Tags: maven, jboss, dns

I am having issue while deploying WAR to my cluster setup which is in domain mode. I am not trying remote deployment, the maven and JBOSS both are running on same machine. As few suggested I have also tried to not use native port for domain mode. Doing following setup in domain.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">
    <show-model value="true"/>
    <remoting-connector  use-management-endpoint="false" />
</subsystem>
```

By default the JBoss remoting is on 9999 and 4447. I am running single node cluster which adds another remoting port with offset 100 as 4547. I have tried all of these port 4447/4547 goes in infinity without error. While 9999 just drops out without any error.

My maven configuration is as following

```
<domain>
    <server-groups>
        <server-group>ha-server-group</server-group>
    </server-groups>
<profiles>
    <profile>ha</profile>
</profiles>
</domain>
<hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
<port>4547</port>
```

Strange part is that maven is able to deploy .jar file using same configuration, but problem arises when I am trying to deploy .war.

Maven console output is as follows, where for .war it specifies what port it is connecting to when I didn't specify any host port configuration.

```
[INFO] --- jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.1.1.Final:deploy (default-cli) @ ABC ---
Oct 18, 2012 5:39:17 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
Oct 18, 2012 5:39:17 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
Oct 18, 2012 5:39:17 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] --- jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.1.0.Final:deploy (default-cli) @ XYZ ---
[INFO] Executing goal deploy on server localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9999.
Oct 18, 2012 5:39:29 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
Oct 18, 2012 5:39:29 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
Oct 18, 2012 5:39:29 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
```

I can deploy using CLI but I am looking for maven based solution..

Comment: I searched bit and took help of Jboss community and switching to 7.2.Final version of plugin did the trick and I could connect to 9999 in domain mode

Answer (score 0):

I searched bit and took help of Jboss community and switching to 7.2.Final version of plugin did the trick and I could connect to 9999 in domain mode